# libpcap missing

Tags: linux, centos, gcc, c

I’m trying to run a C program,
but every time I try to run it I get this message:

```
error while loading shared libraries: libpcap.so.0.8: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I've re-installed `libpcap`; I've installed `gcc` and `g++`; I’ve updated it and I’m lost. I’m not sure what else I can do. Could anyone help out?

Comment: What is the output of `sudo yum provides '*/libpcap.so*'` ?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/iXSWYcrg is the output

Comment: Looks like you have the libs for `libpcap-1.4`.  Do you have the source for your c program? Looks like you will need to recompile and link it.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that compiling this:

```
gcc -o example example.c -l:libpcap.so.1.7.4
```

still requires that

```
libpcap.so.0.8
```

be on your system.

And I have no idea why.  However, making a link from (whatever version you're using, notice I'm EXPLICITLY telling it to link to libpcap.so.1.7.4) whatever version you do have to libpcap.so.0.8 - it will work.